# Is $\int_{-1}^9 (2x-1)^4\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^9 (2x-1)^4\mathrm{d}(2x-1)$ correct?

Tags: definite-integrals, notation

When solving $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^9 (2x-1)^4\mathrm{d}x$, I often find someone doing $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^9 (2x-1)^4\mathrm{d}(2x-1)$. Are the boundary values still correct? Or should we change them as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{17} (2x-1)^4\mathrm{d}(2x-1)$?

Comment: Completely correct, and thus the primitive function of the integrand, on any interval where the integrand is continuous,  equals $$\;\frac{(2x-1)^5}{2\cdot5}$$ .... **yet** don't rush it: your integral is an improper one...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Just curious, what's so improper about the given integral? I just did it with a u-sub and confirmed my answer with DESMOS. It's just FTC. Am I missing something?

Comment: The variable of integration hasn't been changed yet, so we don't do anything with the integration limits at that point.  It is when we then declare that  $ \ u \ = \ 2x \ - \ 1 \ $ that we would then have  $ \ u \ = \ 2 (-1) \ - \ 1 \ = \ -3 \ $ to  $ \ u \ = \ 2 · 9 \ - \ 1 \ = \ 17 \ $ . (I'm not sure where the limits you show are coming from...)

Comment: @boojum: Sorry for my miscalculation. Updated.

Comment: @imranfat You're right: when I wrote that part of my message I saw a fraction...which is nonsensical since I'm giving the primitive. :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing variable, in appropriate conditions, we have general formula
$$\int\limits_{\phi(\alpha)}^{\phi(\beta)}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt$$
in your case taking $x=\phi(t)=\frac{t+1}{2}$ we have mapping $\phi \colon [-3, 17]\to [-1,9]$ with $\phi(-3)=-1$ and $\phi(17)=9$. Obviously $t=\phi^{-1}(x)=2x-1$.